# Adding missing columns to a dataframe pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

When reading data from a text file using `pyspark` using following code,

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = sqlContext.read.option("sep", "|").option("header", "false").csv('D:\\DATA-2021-12-03.txt')
```

My data text file looks like,

```
col1|cpl2|col3|col4
112 |4344|fn1 | home_a| extras| applied | <null>| <empty>
```

But the output I got was,

```
col1|cpl2|col3|col4
112 |4344|fn1 | home_a
```

Is there a way to add those missing columns for the dataframe?

Expecting,

```
col1|cpl2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8
112 |4344|fn1 | home_a| extras| applied | <null>| <empty>
```

Comment: I think that you have to either modify the CSV file header or insert it before you read the file using a csv reader.

Comment: @codebot can you update the expected dataframe

Comment: @Nitish added the expected dataframe

Comment: if you don't care about the names of the existing columns,`option("header", "true")` and passing a custom schema should work, no? (there might some warnings about the header not matching the schema)

Comment: yeah. tried that. but it gives me an error. dataframe conversion is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the schema, instead of infering it.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType 
schema = StructType() \
      .add("col1",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col2",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col3",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col4",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col5",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col6",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col7",StringType(),True) \
      .add("col8",StringType(),True) 

df = spark.read.option("sep", "|").option("header", "true").schema(schema).csv('70475571_data.txt')
```

### Output

```
+----+----+----+-------+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|col1|col2|col3|   col4|   col5|     col6|   col7|    col8|
+----+----+----+-------+-------+---------+-------+--------+
|112 |4344|fn1 | home_a| extras| applied | <null>| <empty>|
+----+----+----+-------+-------+---------+-------+--------+
```